# Ant IncludeTask

Tags: java, ant

I'm writing a `MyTask` that extends `org.apache.tools.ant.Task`

In the `execute()` method of `MyTask` i need to include a file.
I mean i would call the `<include>` task in the execute() method of MyTask.

I looked at the Apache Ant API but i didn't found the class `IncludeTask` that implements the `<include>` task

Where can i find the Include java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `<include>` isn't implemented as `Task` class in the normal way. The logic seems baked into `org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper`, as though `<include>` is handled in a special way.

You may not have much luck trying to leverage that functionality.

Comment: so, is it possible to do something like "call an xml file" in my Task, and in that xml file i use the `<include file=".."/>` statement?

Comment: @alem0lars: Possibly, but probably not easily. I suggest looking through the source of `ProjectHelper` to see how it works. You can provide your own `ProjectHelper` if necessary (http://ant.apache.org/manual/projecthelper.html)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html

For example suppose one wanted to handle objects object of type org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Condition, one may have a class:

```
public class MyTask extends Task {
    private List conditions = new ArrayList();
    public void add(Condition c) {
        conditions.add(c);
    }
    public void execute() {
     // iterator over the conditions
    }
}
```

One may define and use this class like this:

```
<taskdef name="mytask" classname="MyTask" classpath="classes"/>
<typedef name="condition.equals"
         classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.conditions.Equals"/>
<mytask>
    <condition.equals arg1="${debug}" arg2="true"/>
</mytask>
```

Comment: The question was which class implements the `Include` task, not how to *use* the task.

Comment: @skaffman yeah, you're right. I need the java class that implements the Include task, because i'm implementing a custom task (in java)

Comment: @s @a, I think I understand the question now.  I have updated my answer.  Alem0lars, can you update your question to make it more clear?